# Spring MVC - Mapping JSON object from Ajax post request to Java object

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring

I am trying to make an AJAX post request, but my JSON object values do not map to the Java object from my controller. When I debug the the Java object fields, I get null values returned. Please see below for the code.

AJAX request

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var account = {};
    account.type = $('#account-type option:selected').text();
    account.name = $('#account-names option:selected').text();
    account.amount = $(this).find('input[name=amount]').val();

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/spring-mvc-practice/account/create',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(account),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

AccountController.java

```
@Controller
public class AccountController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String createAccount(@ModelAttribute Account account) {
        System.out.println("name = " + account.getName());
        System.out.println("type = " + account.getType());
        System.out.println("amount = " + account.getAmount());      
        return null;
    }
}
```

Account.java

```
public class Account {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private double amount;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

}
```

Debug Results:

> name = null
>      type = null
>      amount = 0.0

I also tried to change `@ModelAttribute` to `@RequestBody` in the controller method (according to this tutorial: https://gerrydevstory.com/2013/08/14/posting-json-to-spring-mvc-controller/), but I get this error when I make the AJAX request:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-practice/account/create 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is it a Spring Boot application or not?

Comment: Hi, I am new to Spring -- I don't think I am using Spring Boot. I am running my app on Tomcat.

Comment: Ok, then you have to configure an ObjectMapper, I think. (It, and many other things comes autoconfigured when you use Spring Boot, and I think using Spring Boot is a better way to learn Spring then not using it)

Comment: try a console.log(account) before $.ajax call, check in browser console is data is getting passed to java.

Comment: Yes, the account JSON object prints out in the console

Comment: Try adding **consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE** in @RequestMapping

Comment: Nope, still getting null values in Java object.

Comment: hi, did you manage to solve this problem? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use `@RequestBody` just replace your `createAccount` method with:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createAccount(@RequestBody final Account account) {
    System.out.println("name = " + account.getName());
    System.out.println("type = " + account.getType());
    System.out.println("amount = " + account.getAmount());      
    return null;
}
```

...your AJAX call should have:

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  url: '/spring-mvc-practice/account/create',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false, // Force requested pages not to be cached by the browser
  processData: false, // Avoid making query string instead of JSON
  data: JSON.stringify(account)
}).done(function (data) {
  console.log('AJAX call was successfully executed ;)');
  console.log('data = ', data);
}).fail(function () {
  console.log('AJAX call failed :(');
});
```

...and the most important, you MUST have this dependency (you can play with the versions in case you can't have that one in particular...notice I'm using Maven) in your classpath:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I replaced my code with what you have there, and also added the dependency, but I get this error when I do the AJAX request: 
POST http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-practice/account/create 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: @DavidFoster that means you can't serialize `Account` into JSON; double check you have the `jackson-databind` in your classpath. Are you using Maven? Additionally, what version of Spring are you using?

Comment: I am using Maven, and the jackson-databind jar is in the same lib folder as my other Spring jars. I am using Spring version 4.1.7

Comment: @DavidFoster there are no `/lib` folder(s) in Maven's projects...unless you are talking about the `/lib` folder inside the generated WAR/EAR file

Comment: Yes the /lib folder inside the WAR

Comment: @DavidFoster I did a smal POC with your stuff since I was wondering why it doesn't works for you? For me it's working, so you might have something different...have a look [here](https://bitbucket.org/vadimvera/spring-mvc)

Answer (score -1):

Please try to assign your paramaeter account to be passed something like this. Since now you are passing them as array which is mostly used to pass list. So for example you want to list of accounts then you will use the syntax above.

But for now pls try this:

```
var account = {type: $('#account-type option:selected').text(),name: $('#account-names option:selected').text(),amount : $(this).find('input[name=amount]').val()};
```

Comment: It's still not working. I am still getting null values in my Java object.

Comment: @David Did you checked from browser dev tool what is the request being sent? In network tab you can see what is the json string its posting to the controller.

Comment: try setting content type to                                                                   contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",

Comment: In the network tab, I see the json in the Request Payload
{type: "Savings", name: "Savings Account", amount: "23123"}

Comment: @David Try keeping contentType: "application/json" remove charset = utf-8